# GLSL fault: syntax error,unexpected IDENTIFIER,expecting RIGHT_PAREN

Tags: glsl

I am trying to use glslangvalidator to compile my shaders ,then it tells me this :
Error :deferred.frag:954: "":syntax error,unexpected IDENTIFIER,expecting RIGHT_PAREN.
Here is where goes wrong:

```
#define FXaaFloat float
#define FxaaFloat4 float4
#if(FXAA_GREEN_AS_LUMA==0)
FxaaFloat FxaaLuma(FxaaFloat4 rgba)
{
     return 0.299*rgba.x+0.587*rgba.y+0.114*rgba.z;
}
#else
FxaaFloat FxaaLuma(FxaaFloat4 rgba)
{
   return rgba.y
}
#endif
```

here is the definition of the FxaaFloat:

Comment: `FxaaFloat` and `FxaaFloat4` muse be defined before the `FxaaLuma` function.

Comment: Are you really defining FxaaFloat twice?

Comment: Now I have refilled more details of my question ,this is my first time asking questions on stackoverflow,sry about that.